# All non-isomorphic graphs with chromatic number 4

Tags: graph-theory

I need to find all non-isomorphic graphs $G=(V,E), |V|=5$ with chromatic number $\chi(G) = 4$. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

HINT: What’s the only graph on $4$ vertices with chromatic number $4$? Start there, and see how you can add a vertex.

**Added:** I did not mean to imply that this will give you all possible graphs on $5$ vertices with chromatic number $4$, but rather that it gives you a good starting point. However, one can show that in fact any graph $G$ on $5$ vertices with chromatic number $4$ *does* contain a copy of $K_4$. Start with $G$, and remove one vertex to get a graph $G'$ on $4$ vertices; if $G'$ is a copy of $K_4$, you’re done. If not, show that $G'$ contains a triangle (because otherwise $\chi(G')\le 2$, and $\chi(G)\le 3$). Finally, show that $G$ must contain a copy of $K_4$.

Comment: There isn't only one: it could be square or line, as I guess.

Comment: @DarkArchon: The square and chain on $4$ vertices both have chromatic number $2$.

Comment: Then it should be 4-complete graph ($K_4$).

Comment: @DarkArchon: That’s right. So you that’s a good place to start.

Comment: Who says that $G$ contains a $K_4$?

Comment: @Christian: Not I, though I see now that my answer could be read that way. I merely suggested that that would be a good place to begin.

Answer (score 2):

Since $G\ne K_5$ we may assume $\{v_4,v_5\}\notin E$. If, e.g., $\{v_1,v_2\}\notin E$ as well then $G$ could be tricolored according to the partition $\{v_1,v_2\}\cup\{v_3\}\cup\{v_4,v_5\}$. It follows that ($G$ restricted to) $T:=\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ is a $K_3$. If both $v_4$ and $v_5$ were connected to at most two vertices of $T$ the graph $G$ again could be tricolored. Therefore we may assume that $v_4$ is connected to all three vertices of $T$, which implies that $Q:=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is a $K_4$. Finally the vertex $v_5$ is connected to $0\leq k\leq3$ vertices of $Q$. It follows that there are four isomorphy types, parametrized by $k$.